# Safe way to get System.Web assembly reference

Tags: asp.net

I am currently using the following line of code in a web server control to get a reference to the loaded System.Web assembly:

```
var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                   .Single(i => i.FullName.Contains("System.Web,"));
```

I am a bit concerned that there could be an occasion where the Single method call fails because (1) the assembly can't be found, or (2) more than one assembly is returned. In the debugger, it looks like there is only one assembly that matches the selector (I've included the comma after System.Web as all of the others show as "System.Web.Whatever"), but this doesn't mean that the FullName of all assemblies loaded will never contain this text).

Is there a better way to identify the reference that I'm looking for so I know that it will always find it correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: For a start you could use "StartsWith" instead of "Contains"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be to use a type that you know is in the System.Web assembly, e.g.:

```
var assembly = typeof(System.Web.HttpContext).Assembly;
```

Comment: Loving this! Works perfectly and much more elegant.